# Difference between next( ) and next( ).CharAt(0);

Tags: java, string, char

I have created an abstract class Employee which displays and calculates the Details of Weekly and Hourly Employee.In the main method i have used switch case for a menu and do while to continue using the program as long as the user want.But I'm getting an Error when compiling the code.:

```
*javac "AbstractDemo.java" (in directory: /home/user/Desktop)
AbstractDemo.java:52: error: incompatible types
    ch=s.next();
             ^
  required: char
  found:    String
1 error
Compilation failed.*
```

This is the Source Code:

```
import java.util.*;
abstract class Employee{
    Employee(float amt,int n){
        float sal;
        System.out.println("The amount paid to Employee is:"+amt);
        sal=amt*n;
        System.out.println("Total Salary is:"+sal);
    }

} 
class WeeklyEmployee extends Employee{
        WeeklyEmployee(float a,int n){
        super(a,n);
    }
}
class HourlyEmployee extends Employee{
        HourlyEmployee(float amt,int hrs){
        super(amt,hrs);
    }
}           

public class AbstractDemo {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int a;
        char ch;
        float amount;
        int hours;
        int weeks;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{

        System.out.println("Enter the choice");
        a=s.nextInt();
        switch (a) {
            case 1 :
        System.out.println("Enter the salary of weekly employee(Per Week):");
        amount=s.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter the total no of week");
        weeks=s.nextInt();
             Employee W=new WeeklyEmployee(amount,weeks);break;
             case 2:

        System.out.println("Enter the salary of hourly employee(Per hour):");
        amount=s.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter the total no of hours");
        hours=s.nextInt();
        Employee H=new HourlyEmployee(amount,hours);break;
            default:System.out.println("Error invalid Choice");
    }
    System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?(Y/N)");
    ch=s.next();
}while (ch== 'y'||ch== 'Y');

}
}
```

But When i use `s.next().ChatAt(0);` the code compiles successfully.Could somebody explain why this is happening?Is Char taking input as String?Or if it is a string why its showing an Error when i edit the while condition to `while(ch=="y"||ch=="Y");` ?

Comment: Compiler talking with you, man! Listen to him. He gives you answer you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ch` is a `char`. `s.next()` returns a `String`. You can't assign a `String` to a `char`. You can assign the first character of the `String` to a `char`, which is what you do in `ch = s.next().charAt(0);`.

It's a good thing you are not trying `while(ch=="y"||ch=="Y")`, since that would fail even if you changed `ch` to be a `String` (which would allow it to pass compilation, but wouldn't give the expected result), since you can't compare `String`s in Java with `==` (you should use `equals` instead).

Answer (score 1):

`s.next()` returns the next String object. But `s.next().charAt(0)` returns the first character of the next String object. Hence its expecting character and throwing error

Answer (score 1):

the method `next()` of the `Scanner` object returns a `String`. So in order for your assignment to work, you need to extract the first character from this string using the `charAt()` method.

And since ch is a character not String, `while(ch == "y" || ch == "Y")` won't work.

Use `while(ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')` instead.

*(single quotes = character, double quotes = string)*

Answer (score 1):

This because **ch** is **char** and your idea is input single letter Y or N to stop or continue your program. But, you use method next() of Scanner that return a String. That's main reason why you get this

`*javac "AbstractDemo.java" (in directory: /home/user/Desktop)
AbstractDemo.java:52: error: incompatible types
    ch=s.next();
             ^
  required: char
  found:    String
1 error
Compilation failed.*`

When you try to use **s.next().ChatAt(0)**. It mean that you try to get first character from input.
-> this is just imcompatible types error when you try to assign String to Char without converting it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use s.next(), it is read as a string. That's why you get an error with ch=s.next()

However, s.next().charAt(0) will return a char value which can be used by your variable.

Likewise, when you compare char ch to 'y', it compares two chars, but "y" reads as a string and would cause a type mismatch.